# How to push all the values in array?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this:

```
z: [[res.push(this.Map.heatmap[0])]],
```

so this is just one value. But how can I push all the values of the array

and this is the interface:

```
export interface map { 
    
}
```

I have a array of 100 values in it:

```
10
```

but if I do this:

```
 this.Map().subscribe((res) => {
      
            zsmooth: 'best'
          }
        ],
```

not all the values are loaded. So how to load all the values?

and this is how I have the object:

```
Map: map = {};
```

Thank you

Oke,

```
console.log(res)
```

gives back array with 100 values:

```
length: 100
```

but apperently this:

```
    z: [[res]],
```

doesn't work. I dont see the value at all.

But if I do this:

```
hallo: console.log(res.push(this.Map.map[0])),
            z: [[res.push(this.cMap.tmap[0])]],
```

it returns the number 2

Comment: thank you but not realy.  z: [[res.concat((this.cameraAgretateHeadMap.heatmap))]], doenst work

Comment: What I have to fill in for index?

Comment: z: [[res.push((this.cameraAgretateHeadMap.heatmap[]))]],

Comment: Your edit doesn't make it any more clear to me. "_I have a array of 100 values in it_" Which array? `res`? `this.cameraAgretateHeadMap.heatmap`? `this.cameraAgretateHeadMap.heatmap[0]`? It would really help if you could add what values `res` contains _before_ the push, which values `this.cameraAgretateHeadMap.heatmap` contains and what the expected result should look like.

Comment: What you are logging/putting in `z` is the return value of `.push()` (which returns the new length of the array), _not_ the resulting array. You need to first push the elements and _then_ add `res` to your object.

Comment: HI Ivar, can you give example

Comment: [Like so](https://jsfiddle.net/7pcvh45y/). But that only applies for `.push()`. If you're using `.concat`, then it shouldn't really matter is that _does_ return the new concatenated array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225782/discussion-between-codeisnice-and-ivar).

Comment: can we go to discussion

Comment: Are you in chat? I tried that. but page is blanco

Answer (score 0):

concat function is maybe what you are looking for:

```
var array1 = [A, B, C];
var array2 = [D, E, F];
var newArray = array1.concat(array2);

The newArray will be [A,B,C,D,E,F]
```

In your case you would do something like:

```
z = z.concat(this.cameraAgretateHeadMap.heatmap)
```

a little bit more code from your side would have been helpful to understand it in a better what your problem is!

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thank you. I edit the question.